# Accessing Salesforce Developer Edition through API

Tags: rest-api, developer-edition

I want to use our Salesforce Developer Edition and access our data through the API. I have setup an additional user (User License: Salesforce Platform License, Profile: Standard Platform User) to use as my API user, and I have a few questions:

- Does the Salesforce Platform License grant this API-User enough rights to synchronize Account-Data (read and write) through the API?
- Can I use this user as my API user, even though the API-only checkbox does not appear in the Developer Edition? The "API enabled"-Checkbox appears, however, and is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the Salesforce Platform License grant this API-User enough rights to synchronize Account-Data (read and write) through the API?

API access is primarily per-org, not per-user, so assuming your org has permission to use the API, and the profile in question has API Enabled, then yes, you can use the API.

> Can I use this user as my API user, even though the API-only checkbox does not appear in the Developer Edition? The "API enabled"-Checkbox appears, however, and is enabled.

API Only is used to restrict UI logins; a user with *this* permission can only use the API and cannot log in through the browser. The API Enabled permission allows the user to use the API.